# How to a call method from another class in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can anyone tell me how to call `add_row` method from `def test(self):` method in `User` class ?
Now i am using code for call `Rows().add_row()`.I print something in def `add_row(self):` then it prints but not add widget in screen.

## test.py

```
class User(Popup):

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def test(self):
        Rows().add_row()

class narration(BoxLayout):
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?", "?"])
    button_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(narration, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Rows(BoxLayout):
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(narration(button_text=str(self.row_count)))
```

Comment: What relation is there between `User` and `Rows`? How would you know which `Rows` instance to call `add_row` on, unless you pass said instance as a parameter?

Comment: Make object of "Rows" Class and pass it to "User" class in init make it self and with the help pf that object call add_row() method of  "Rows" class

Answer (score 0):

```
class User(Popup):

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.row_obj = obj

    def test(self):
        self.row_obj.add_row()


class narration(BoxLayout):
    col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?", "?"])
    button_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(narration, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(narration(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


rows_obj = Rows()
user_obj = User(rows_obj)
```

It it not a working code it's just an example But your approach should be something like that.If you don't want to pass object of "Rows" class than make "User" class as a child of "Rows" class using inheritance concept.

```
class User(Rows,Popup):
```

Answer (score -1):

I changed your code a little to show you how it's done.

### in tmp.py

```
class Rows(object):
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        print "Hello"
        # self.add_widget(narration(button_text=str(self.row_count)))

class User(Rows):

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def test(self):
        self.add_row()

class narration(object):
    # col_data = ListProperty(["?", "?", "?"])
    # button_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(narration, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

I had to comment out some lines in order to get it working.

### now, in tmp2.py

```
from tmp import User

if __name__ == '__main__':
    temp = User("H")
    temp.test()
    # outputs : Hello
```

What we did is instanciating the User class such as :

`class User(Rows):`, so when you will call User class, with the proper `super()` statement, you will be able to use the **methods** of **Rows** as you would use it as if it was defined **in User class**.

So you will call (it has been modified in the code) : `self.add_row()`, even if `add_row()` is a method from **Rows**.

Comment: This is a total WTF. Inheritance implies a "is a" relationship, and I really don't think a  `User` is a `Row`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You will agree with me that the question is quite unclear. He wants to use `add_row()` method from `Rows()` class, who am I to judge, I am just giving him the way to do this.

Comment: if the question is unclear then post a comment asking for clarifications. The "solution" you posted is a common newbie mistake and almost never the right solution.

Comment: I will gladly look at an advanced user solution and learn if you have one. I'm always willing to learn !